# Is it possible to map (JPA) a Java type hierarchy that uses generics in the abstract superclass?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I've been reading lots of SO questions and blog posts and documentation about JPA mapping, but nothing seems to clearly address my situation (which surprises me, since I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to map a class hierarchy like this).

I have a nice, cleanly-designed object model that I need to map via JPA. It's as follows

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T extends BaseEntity> {
    private Integer id;
    private List<T> children;
}

public class ConcreteEntity1 extends BaseEntity<ConcreteEntity2> {
    private String value;
}

public class ConcreteEntity2 extends BaseEntity{
    private String foo;
}
```

I can't seem to get this to map at all. The closest I've gotten is like this (I'm using XML mapping now, although I've also tried with annotations):

```
<mapped-superclass class="com.me.datamodel.BaseEntity" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="auto_id" nullable="false"/>
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>

<entity class="com.me.datamodel.ConcreteEntity1" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="value" />
        <one-to-many name="children" fetch="EAGER" mapped-by="media">
            <cascade><cascade-all /></cascade>
        </one-to-many>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.me.datamodel.ConcreteEntity2" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="foo" />
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

The problem with this is that JPA complains about the mapping of `children` in `ConcreteEntity1`. It claims that the target entity of `children` (BaseEntity) is not an entity. Well, that's correct, 'BaseEntity' not an entity. But the actual type of `children` is *not* `BaseEntity` but rather `ConcreteEntity2` (as declared by `ConcreteEntity1`'s type parameter).

So how can I map an object model like this? I've tried quite a few variations but none worked (they all fail during initialization of the entity manager).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I fixed the code to correctly show that `ConreteEntity1` and `ConcreteEntity2` both extend `BaseEntity`.

Comment: Once I assign it I can't undo, so I'm just going to wait until all integration tests have shown that there are no issues created with this mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made almost everything correct, except extending correctly `BaseEntity` in `ConcreteEntity2`: you forgot to say the type parameter like `public class ConcreteEntity2 extends BaseEntity<ConcreteEntity2> {...}`. Because of this it could not map `ConcreteEntity2` and therefore `ConcreteEntity1`.

So my working code (tested with EclipseLink 2.5.1 and Hibernate 4.3.1.Final):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T extends BaseEntity> {
    private Integer id;
    private List<T> children;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<T> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<T> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}

@Entity
public class ConcreteEntity1 extends BaseEntity<ConcreteEntity2> {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
@Entity
public class ConcreteEntity2 extends BaseEntity<ConcreteEntity2> {
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

**Some important notes:** in every entity that JPA tries to map, if the persistent field is a collection, then it MUST be a collection of entity type (JPA specification chapter *2.2 Persistent fields and properties*). If you do not know what exactly are the children of `ConcreteEntity2` (except that they are `BaseEntity`), you must either make `BaseEntity` an entity, or introduce another entity to be extended by all possible child-classes and use it instead. In any of the above mentioned cases you will have to play with JPA inheritance.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the key was having to specify the type parameter on every subclass that is an @Entity. It's still not clear to me why JPA/Hibernate requires that (obviously Java doesn't), but I can live with it.

Comment: The biggest disappointment with this is that the errors I got gave no indication about how to resolve this. They pointed in all different directions (depending on the various things I tried), but never at the concrete class that had no type parameter.

Comment: I can explain that: I mentioned in my answer that every persistent collection MUST contain only entities. And because you did not specify the type when extending, every Java code sees actually that that list is of type `List<T extends BaseEntity>`, but BaseEntity is not an entity.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed not self-explanatory what exactly causes the problem. But it comes with the experience/time.